# Weird space on the right side on lower resolutions screens with Reponsive Webdesign

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

As you can see here: http://www.responsinator.com/?url=www.vaneldijk.nl there is an extra space on lower resolution devices. I've tried using firebug and webmaster toolbar to figure out what is causing this to happen but so far no luck. The CSS can be found here: http://www.vaneldijk.nl/sites/all/themes/prestige/css/style.css.

I've build tons of responsive websites without this problem so hopefully someone can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of testing I finally found the solution. Make sure your wrap elements (so your direct elements in your body) have an 'overflow: hidden' declaration in your css. So for example this your HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="wrap">Your website content</div>
</body>
```

Your CSS should look like this

```
#wrap{
overflow:hidden;
}
```

This will remove the weird space in Opera.

Answer (score 1):

Change this it makes the page 100% width.

```
#wrap .inside, #footer .inside {
text-align: left;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Yes it does. But it doesn't solve the problem. The weird gap still exists.